# How import all information of location history KML file on Fusion Table?

Tags: kml, google-fusion-tables, location-history

I exported the KML file from locationhistory of google maps.

Thus, I try to create a Fusion Table using Google drive and importing this file.

During the import I selected the row that contains column names.

The columns created in fusion table are:
description, name and geometry

The Fusion Table import only one row with description and name filled, while geometry field is empty.

- Are Geography information on Fusion table fused in geometry type ?
- If it's right, why it doesn't work?
- If it's wrong, what is the correctly type mapping for these information?

Here the KML file used (removed some entries about gx:coord):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
<name>Location history from 09/21/2014 to 09/28/2014</name>
<open>1</open>
<description/>
<StyleMap id="multiTrack">
<Pair>
<key>normal</key>
<styleUrl>#multiTrack_n</styleUrl>
</Pair>
<Pair>
<key>highlight</key>
<styleUrl>#multiTrack_h</styleUrl>
</Pair>
</StyleMap>
<Style id="multiTrack_n">
<IconStyle>
<Icon>
<href>http://earth.google.com/images/kml-icons/track-directional/track-0.png</href>
</Icon>
</IconStyle>
<LineStyle>
<color>99ffac59</color>
<width>6</width>
</LineStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="multiTrack_h">
<IconStyle>
<scale>1.2</scale>
<Icon>
<href>http://earth.google.com/images/kml-icons/track-directional/track-0.png</href>
</Icon>
</IconStyle>
<LineStyle>
<color>99ffac59</color>
<width>8</width>
</LineStyle>
</Style>
<Placemark>
<name>Latitude User</name>
<description>Location history for Latitude User from 09/21/2014 to 09/28/2014</description>
<styleUrl>#multiTrack</styleUrl>
<gx:Track>
<altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
<when>2014-09-21T15:23:46.249-07:00</when>
<gx:coord>99.99999 41.99999 0</gx:coord>
<when>2014-09-21T15:23:47.249-07:00</when>
<gx:coord>99.99999 41.99999 0</gx:coord>
</gx:Track>
</Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The supported geometry-types when you import KML are Linestring, Polygon and Point (see: https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/174680 )

This would work:

```
<Placemark>
  <name>Latitude User</name>
  <description>Location history for Latitude User from 09/21/2014 to 09/28/2014</description>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>99.99999,41.99999,0</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>
```

Comment: I understand. Is there a way to import it in the original format? I need to apply a filter based on "when" field.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't possible. You'll need to create separate rows for each datetime/coordinates pair to be able to setup a filter.